# What configurations are needed in Kafka-Ignite Sink Connector when connectivity is remote?

Tags: caching, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I did not find any specific documentation on Apache Ignite Sink Connector. I am using a Kafka ignite sink connector, for which I have added jars and I am able to see the connector in control center. I want to push Kafka topic data in ignite where Kafka and ignite are on remote nodes. My connector should ideally run on a remote node from the ignite node.

How can I achieve this?
What configurations I need to pass in the spring xml file which I pass as a parameter in connector properties?
What configurations I need to pass in the spring xml file of the ignite server node?

Comment: You found no documentation at all?? https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/streaming/kafka-streamer#streaming-data-via-kafka-connect

Comment: I meant documentation which specifies xml file content through which connector can identify ignite nodes

Comment: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/config/example-default.xml + https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/understanding-configuration